# Clojure loop with cond

Tags: clojure, prime-factoring

I am working on a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problem that involves factoring numbers and have written the following function to do that.

```
(defn get-factors [value]
  (let [max-factor (->> (Math/sqrt value)
                        (Math/floor)
                        (Math/round))
        ifactors #{}]
   (loop [n 2 factors ifactors]
     (do 
       (println (format ">> N: %d, Factors: %s" n factors))
       (cond
        (when (> n max-factor)   ; exit of we have passed the max-factor
          (do 
            (println (format "--Exiting(%d): %s" n factors))
            factors))               ; return factors
        (when (= 0 (mod value n)); have we found a factor?   
          (do 
            (println (format"--Factor(%d)" n))
            (recur (inc n) (conj factors n (/ value n)))))   ; recurse: add _n_ and reciprocal _n_ to list
        :default (do             ; otherwise
                   (println (format"--default(%d): %s" n (= 0 (mod value n))))
                   (recur (inc n) factors)) ; recurse: increment _n_, dont modify factors
        )))))
```

However, the function is returning `nil` and my println statements are evaluated in a strange order.  Here is the output from the REPL for `(get-factors 12)`, which should return `#{2,3,4,6}`:

```
>> N: 2, Factors: #{}
--default(2): true
>> N: 3, Factors: #{}
--default(3): true
>> N: 4, Factors: #{}
--Exiting(4): #{}
--Factor(4)
>> N: 5, Factors: #{3 4}
--Exiting(5): #{3 4}
```

As you can see, the default state is being hit even though the `(= 0 (mod value n))` of the previous case evaluates to true.  Likewise, the exit condition is hit twice.  The last case evaluated should be for n=3, but you can see output for up to n=5.

I'm obviously doing something fundamentally wrong but I am not seeing what.  (Related, is there a better way to go about constructing a list?)

Comment: For one, You need to provide `cond` with pairs of expressions - a test expression and an expression to evaluate if the test passes: `(cond (> x 10) (print "x is gt 10"), (< x 10) (println "x is less than 10))`. Remove the `when` wrappers.

Comment: danneu I think that is the actual answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is an implicit "when" (or "if") in the test part of any `cond` so you should not be using `when` yourself inside that test.

Second, you are using a single form, a `when` form, as the entire branch of the `cond`, therefore, the `cond` does not see the second form it expects when the test is true.

Check out this example of a proper `cond`:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/cond

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'd been staring at this all afternoon knowing it was something simple.  I did a lot of heavy xsl scripting once upon a time, so the (when ...) clauses looked perfectly natural

Answer (score 0):

If, as others have suggested, you strip out all the crud - the `when`s and `do`s and `println`s - your program works!

A few suggestions:

- Use `quot` instead of `/` to get an integer quotient.
- You might as well start your threading macro thus: `(->> value (Math/sqrt) ... )`.
- Use `:else`, not `:default` or anything else to introduce the catch-all clause in your `cond`.